# How to store and access tokens for authentication?

Tags: node.js, express

```js
app.post('/users/login', (req, res) => {
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);

  Users.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password).then((user) => {
         user.generateAuthTokens().then((token) => {
           res.header('x-auth', token).end();
         })
      }).catch((e) => res.send(e));
  });
```

In the above code `user.generateAuthTokens()` returns the token for specific user. I want to store the token in the Local Storage so that I can have access to it in every  page. I have used the `res.header()` to set the token, but it's not working and also how can I read the stored token in the client side?? I have used `jsonwebtoken` to create tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the token in the res.send

```js
Users.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password)
  .then((user) => {
    user.generateAuthTokens()
    .then((token) => {
      res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });
    })
  })
  .catch((e) => res.send(e));
```

and save on the client side using the browser's localstorage in the frontend:

```js
// To Save
localStorage.setItem('token', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c')


// To Access
localStorage.getItem('token')
```

or you can also set the token in your HTTP Client

If your use Axios

```js
// Example HTTP request with axios
axios.post('/login', {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
    
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });


// Set to default header Authorization with token
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('token')
```

Comment: (node:22148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined.
I am getting this error

Comment: You must save this token in your browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc ...).
In the Backend being only used to generate and send the code.

Comment: okay i got it but i am not understanding how can i send data to front end an use that data in front end can u please give some examples

Comment: @AmandeepSaini I edited the post, take a look to see if this is it

Comment: I prefer  your res.send({token}) to send the token to the client but how to access that token in the front end script(client script) to store in the local Storage. Please this is my last doubt i am stuck at this part from 2 days. please help me last time.. thank you somuch

Comment: Your answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I think your **app.post** is wrong. You making an api end point?
and encrypt the password before saving it in database. From your code it seems you are saving it as it is.
You can also store token in cookies or local storage.

Comment: app.post is for login. After we enter the email and password the user.generateAuthTokens() will generate a token an i want to save it in the local storage so please tell me the steps to do it